# How to increase server load?

Tags: solaris, java, load

I am attempting to stress a server as much as I can before it goes into production. I’m using Jmeter and have been able to add a little more stress by modifying scripts.  I’ve also modified JVM options but still not enough.  What are some of the best ways to increase server load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several ways to do that. You can simply use `dd`, like :

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
```

Or there are other tools like `stress` :

```
stress --cpu 2 --timeout 60
```

The above will stress two cores for 60 seconds.
Or you can also use an endless `while` loop :

```
while true; do true; done
```

Another possibility is this fork bomb - careful with this as it might even crash your computer :

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

There are many other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks Mazs.  I'm a Developer and have been tasked with this so excuse my novelty. Where would this dd command be ran?  Probably a System Admin needs to do it?  Where would the while loop be placed?  Configuration file?

Comment: All of these should be executed in a terminal / bash. The `dd` command is usually present on every Linux system. `while` and the fork bomb are bash internal commands. `stress` is an external tool, must be installed (here is a link on howto install stress on Solaris : https://www.opencsw.org/package/stress/).

Comment: but these will increase load on the OS level - do you want to increase load for the Java server, like generating traffic and requests and so on ?

Comment: Yes.  Load on Java Server.  Web Traffic/ requests, etc.

Comment: yeah thats a different thing....on others forums ppl speak about Jmeter, The Grinder, Pylot, but i think you have to create more complex tests to really stress the server. There is more info on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/performing-a-stress-test-on-web-application